# Web 2.0 & JavaScript Framework

Tags: javascript-framework

We are designing an ASP.NET website. The client asked us to have the website with *Web 2.0 features*.

Would you please provide any good reference material links to achieve this *Web 2.0*?
I need one more clarification please. May I know out of JQuery / Prototype / Other which one is the latest JavaScript framework that designers are using in designing websites?

Answer (score 1):

See **[Web 2.0 Reference Center](http://www.programmableweb.com/reference)**

[**Comparison of JavaScript frameworks**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks)

I prefer using **jQuery** because of

1. Huge user base
2. Plenty of plugins
3. Good documentation

Answer (score 0):

I'm using MooTools and I love it, though if I hadn't known any JS library syntax, I'll go ahead and start with JQuery. At the end they all seem to give the same features, but JQuery I believe is more popular and for example, even here you can get more answers to your questions.

Regarding web 2.0:

http://oreilly.com/web2/archive/what-is-web-20.html

and famous 2.0 websites can be found here:

http://www.digitaltrends.com/how-to/the-best-of-web-20/